# Как автоматически контролировать скорость вращения кулеров? Asus BQ001

Tags: linux, cpu, manjaro, amd

Имеется ноутбук **Asus FX505DY-BQ001** с установленной Manjaro на борту, процессор Ryzen. В простое они шуршат на средней мощности и создают довольно таки громкий звук. Даже при 0% они активно работают в сравнение с виндой, в которой у кулеров при 0% загрузки cpu случается затишье. Установил **amd-ucode**, **tlp**. Пытался разобраться с **TLP**, но недостаточно знаний, а готовых подходящих конфигов не нашел. Чем можно автоматически контролировать скорость кулеров?

Comment: https://01.org/blogs/qwang59/2018/how-achieve-s0ix-states-linux

Comment: В биосе включить cool'n'quiet? И выключить все управляшки из системы.

Comment: @eri нет в биосе этой функции. Почитал про нее, говорят, что её давно убрали.

Comment: С выключенным управлением кулерами мне кадется работет лучше. Ноуты асер и леново.

Comment: @eri может быть, но как я и описал, шум стоит приличный даже при нулевой нагрузке

Comment: В биосе нет настройки минимальной скорости или там перфоманс моде,  квает моде?

Comment: @eri буквально только что посмотрел все вкладки в биосе - нет даже намека на управление кулерами. Только в главном меню показывает текущую скорость оборотов, но там ее контролировать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo pacman -Syu lm_sensors
```

Есть ещё какой-то отдельный fancontrol, но мне и функционала `lm_sensors` хватает.
После установки `man fancontrol` и `man pwmconfig`.
После настройки `sudo systemctl enable --now fancontrol`